# extract groups from a certain OU , but excluding only one

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I want to extract all AD groups from certain OU structure which contains many sub OU's, but I want to exclude only one OU.
In this moment I have this command which extract all groups, but I don't know how to add an exclusion parameter.

```
Get-ADGroup -filter 'groupcategory -eq "security"' -SearchBase "OU=00,OU=AGC,DC=abc,DC=def,DC=net" -server abc | Measure-Object
```

For example I want to exclude **OU named Groups** which is under main path "**OU=GROUPS**,OU=00,OU=AGC,DC=abc,DC=def,DC=net"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a couple ways

1. change your -filter to include a condition to exclude said group like `groupcategory -eq "security" -and name -ne "groups"` or `groupcategory -eq "security" -and distinguishedName -ne "OU=GROUPS,OU=00,OU=AGC,DC=abc,DC=def,DC=net"`
2. Pipe to a where statement

```
Get-ADGroup -filter 'groupcategory -eq "security"' -SearchBase "OU=00,OU=AGC,DC=abc,DC=def,DC=net" -server abc |
    ? { $_.distinguishedName -ne "OU=GROUPS,OU=00,OU=AGC,DC=abc,DC=def,DC=net" } |
    Measure-Object
```